# python autopy grab screen rectangle

Tags: python, automation, ui-automation, autopy

I am using autopy module to grab screen and save it to file.

`autopy.bitmap.capture_screen()` works great but how can I grab specific portion of screen x=0, y=10, width=200px, height=100px?

In autopy source is something like this but **I have no idea how to pass rect variable in autopy.bitmap.capture_screen()?** 
I tried autopy.bitmap.capture_screen([0,10,200,100]) but it does not work - TypeError: Argument is not a rect

```
static PyObject *bitmap_capture_screen(PyObject *self, PyObject *arg)
{
    MMRect rect;
    MMBitmapRef bitmap = NULL;
    MMSize displaySize = getMainDisplaySize();

    if (arg == NULL || arg == Py_None) {
        rect = MMRectMake(0, 0, displaySize.width, displaySize.height);
    } else {
        if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(arg, "(kk)(kk)", &rect.origin.x,
                                               &rect.origin.y,
                                               &rect.size.width,
                                               &rect.size.height)) {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "Argument is not a rect");
            return NULL;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to define rectangle.

```
rect = ((10, 10), (1, 1))
autopy.bitmap.capture_screen( rect )
```